# Saving edit text, text views, radio buttons on fragment replace

Tags: android

I have an app where the user has to fill up a form. It has many text views, edit texts, and radio buttons.

If i replace that fragment later, how do I preserve the data if i go back to that replaced/previous fragment?

Comment: you just have to save the values to sharedpreferences when the fragment is detached or destroyed then call the values on the onCreate or onResume();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options available. Try any of them.

**Option 1: Use Shared Preferences**

[Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

**Option 2: Use Parcelable**

[Android Parcelable Example – Passing data between activities](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)

**Option 3: Use Fragment Save Instance State**

[Probably be the best way (?) to save/restore Android Fragment’s state so far](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/best-approach-to-keep-android-fragment-state/en)